# Insert multiple data in the same column of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database where a comment is stored in a column and I show it in a `TextBox` in my C# application. What I want to do is that you can continue inserting more comments in that same column so that each time it is consulted you can see the new comments with line breaks.

I thought of the `UPDATE` but the problem that when the person saves the comment the other one will be updated by the new one they just entered

Comment: What you *describe* is an item with a 1:m relationship - each item can have *many* comments.  Why not code it that way?

Comment: You should be inserting a new row for each new comment, now updating the existing row.

Comment: It depends if you want to consider these all as one big comment, or you care about recording that they are separate and were added at different times (and maybe by different people?). If the latter then create a second table with a foreign key linking back to the first one, where you can store each comment (and its metadata) in a separate row. That would be considered a properly normalised structure

Comment: And yes your original idea has a concurrency problem as you've noted, so if that's the case then you definitely need a child table for this. (You _could_ solve that using version checking but it's not very efficient really)

Comment: Are you using a relational db? Probably not the best choice. MongoDB might suit your app better.

Comment: you can always concatenate multiple comments into a single column in the presentation layer

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `update`:

```
update t
    set comment = comment + '
' + @new_comment
    where id = @id;
```

You can also store comments in a separate table, with one line per comment.

If you are only every looking at all the comments together, then `update` is a reasonable solution.  More likely, though, you might want additional information about each change, such as:

- Who made the change?
- When was the new comment line added?

And you might want to delete or modify particular comment lines.  For these reasons, a separate table with one row per comment line might be more appropriate.